# How to have two buttons for the same Form passing the same model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC4` application. What I'm trying to do is allow the user to add rows to table, then filling them with data, if necessary add another row and so on until he wants to save his work.

Using standartd `@Html.BeginForm` and an Action method `AddRow(MyViewModel model)` I've managed to do this. However in the same form I want to add another button let's say :

```
 <input type="submit" value="Add row" />
 <input type="submit" id="save-form" value="Save table" />
```

And when `Save table` is clicked I want to pass the model to another action like `SaveCustomTable(MyViewModel mode)` where I'll save the data and so on.

I've looked at the internet about possible solutions and found this one :

```
$(function () {
    $('#save-form').click(function () {
        $(form).attr('action', 'Url.Action( "action1" )')
               .submit();
        return false; // prevent default submission
    });
});
```

However my poor knowledge of jQuery is preventing me from making it working completely. First - is this ok and will it work in general? And if so what should I pass as arguments to `$(form).attr(...)` in order for this to work for action `Foo` in controller `Bar`? And will it submit the model as the other button that has no jQuery attached to him?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you add the event handlers for both buttons, and set form action in these handlers. I think it will be more clearly:

```
$(function () {
    $('#addRowBtn').click(function () {
        $(form).attr('action', $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
    $('#saveTableBtn').click(function () {
        $(form).attr('action', $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
});
```

In you view, add additional attribute and save here required action:

```
<input type="submit" id="addRowBtn" rel="@Url.Action("action1")" value="Add row" re />
<input type="submit" id="saveTableBtn" rel="@Url.Action("action2")" value="Save table" />
```

Comment: I'm, trying this but I get into the same action. 'Url.Action("action1")' - here on `"action1"` I just have to put the name of my action right?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, it's what I used to handle multiple Submit buttons in MVC and It still works in an MVC4 and MVC5 project.

[Multiple submit buttons with ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/)

However it seems like your save button would be a submit, and the Add Row would just be a plain button would it not?